# how to stop container in a grid from expanding when adding text?

Tags: html, css

how to stop the grid items in a grid from expanding when adding text as when I type in

, the width of the boxes increases and flow over the main container "grid5" ?
[

Comment: Can you provide some code so we can understand what exactly you trying to achieve.

Comment: I solved it by making minmax for rows/columns                                                          grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));